# How to display popover next to textbox in Ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs, textbox, popup, popover

I want to display popover(with message) next to textbox when user clicks on textbox using Ext JS. Can anyone please help me in this?

For copy rights I have removed the text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `focus` and `blur` listeners to the textfield.

Inside the `focus` event the first argument is the textfield. The text you add to the window is inside the `textfield.popupText`.

EXAMPLE

```
    xtype: 'textfield',

    popup: null,
    popupText: 'Testing Popup Text',

    listeners: {
        focus: function(field) {
            field.suspendEvent('blur');
            field.suspendEvent('focus');

            field.popup = field.popup || Ext.create({
                xtype: 'window',
                ownerCt: field,
                height: 80,
                width: 200,
                html: field.popupText
            });
            
            field.popup.showBy(field.el, 'l-r')

            field.focus();
            field.resumeEvent('blur');
            field.resumeEvent('focus')
        },
        blur: function(field) {
            field.popup.destroy();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, @Dinkheller, thanks for your reply, however it is giving me runtime error saying "libs.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')" while it is trying to create window popup

Comment: Hi, @Dinkheller, it worked, thanks. I had to slightly modified the code. Instead of Ext.create({}) I had to create it using Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{})

Comment: Hi, @Dinkheller, when I click on textbox it calls blur event immediately and destroy my popup. What can I do to destroy popup when someone clicks outside textbox?

Comment: Hi Ripal. It should always blur, when you leave the textbox. If it does not you might want to add the listener logic to the controller and save the _popup for all fields (there can be only one at a time). In the controller you listen for click on Ext.getBody() and on click destroy the _popup. But again, it should not be necessary.

Comment: If you setup a fiddle, I can fill in the rest.